# Android 10, API29: Writing a file using a C++ library in the application folder crashes the app

Tags: android, c++, qt, gdal

My android app is written in C++ using [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) library and as an external library I have [GDAL](https://gdal.org/). At some point in the app I am creating a DataSet (a file) in the app directory `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.myapp/files` where you should normally have write permissions using [GDALOpen](https://gdal.org/api/raster_c_api.html#gdal_8h_1a6836f0f810396c5e45622c8ef94624d4) function.
The call looks something like this:
`GDALCreate(_driver, outputPath, xSize, ySize, rasterBandCount, _dataType, nullptr)`

**It works on Android 9 but not on Android 10.**

Is there a way to get the "raw" path (as string not as [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)) together with permissions such that I can pass it to my external library (GDAL) in order to write the file?
Similar to what you can do with Storage Access Framework where you get back an `Uri` but my external library doesn't know how to deal with `Uri` objects, only with paths as strings.

Comment: `the app directory Android/data/com.app.myapp/files` That is not a valid directory path. An app directory would be something like `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.myapp/files`. Is it added automagically?

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown? If you catch the exception your app does not have to crash and you could report the problem to the user.

Comment: @blackapps I've updated the path, you're right, the path contains `/storage/emulated/0/` as well. It works perfectly on android 9, that's why I think it's most likely a permissions problem.

Comment: The app does not need any permission to write in its own private folder. Also not on Q. Which exception causes the crash?

Comment: `Is there a way to get the "raw" path (as string) ` I do not understand the question. You have the path already. Or what would be outputPath? The type?

Comment: Somehow to make sure at the same time that you have permissions to write at that location (here is not the case because you have write permissions by default). Similar to doing it using Storage Access Framework via Android SDK but without getting a Uri back because my external lib doesn't know about Uri objects.